# How to sort against Voucher's No which contain hyphen like SI-18-08-1, CRV-18-09-1

Tags: t-sql

I want to sorting against the voucher's in ascending order against the party.

Not tried yet.

```
select * 
from 
  (select v.VoucherDate,
    case 
      when v.VoucherNo like 'SI%' then 'a' 
      else 'b' 
    end as [Type]
    ,v.Particular
    ,v.VoucherNo,isnull((at.Debit),0) as Debit
    ,isnull((at.Credit),0) as Credit 
  from Vouchers v
  left join 
  (select 
    at.VoucherId
    ,at.PartyId 
    ,isnull(SUM(at.DebitAmount),0) as Debit
    ,isnull(sum(at.CreditAmount),0) as Credit 
    from AccountsTransaction at 
    where at.PartyId=5106
    group by at.VoucherId,at.PartyId
    ) at  on at.VoucherId=v.VoucherId
  where at.PartyId=5106
  ) as Temptbale
order by Temptbale.VoucherDate
```

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

If the `VoucherNo` will always contain 4 parts, separated by dashes (and will not contain any dot) I would split it using `PARSENAME` and sort by each component:

```
DECLARE @Vouchers TABLE (VoucherNo VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT INTO @Vouchers (VoucherNo)
VALUES ('SI-18-08-1'),('CRV-18-09-1')

SELECT *
FROM @Vouchers
ORDER BY PARSENAME(REPLACE(VoucherNo,'-','.'),4), 
         PARSENAME(REPLACE(VoucherNo,'-','.'),3), 
         PARSENAME(REPLACE(VoucherNo,'-','.'),2), 
         PARSENAME(REPLACE(VoucherNo,'-','.'),1)
```

Comment: ...And each part will be no longer than `sysname` which is currently 128 chars IIRC.